# Can not reinstall php5 on lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu, php

I want to reinstall php5 on ubuntu but can not get it to install successfully.
The message  I receive after `sudo apt-get install php5` is :

```
sudo apt-get install php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 201 not upgraded.
```

help me please.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

> php5 is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0
>   to remove and 201 not upgraded.

This proves that you alrady have php5 in your system.

---

Simply in your command you are not reinstalling you are installing/updating:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

The correct syntax is to add the `--reinstall` just like:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5
```

Comment: I'm uninstall php5 then I want to new install  but it not install

Comment: according to the output you already have php5 in your system